# Why is the differential the change in the tangent line to a curve?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

In discussing linearization, Stewart defines $dy = f'(x) dx$, where $dy$ is a dependent variable and $dx$ is an independent one.  So far so good.  This is the equation of a line that goes through the origin because if $dx = 0$, $dy = 0$.  Why is this equation used as the change in a tangent line if not all tangent lines go through the origin?  I haven't understood that.

Comment: Which edition are you referring to? In the 7th edition of Early Transcendentals, I see no mention of going through the origin.

Comment: Stewart didn't say that.  I'm saying that.  He defines that $dy$ is a variable relative to $dx$ and $f'(x)$ is a number.  It is true that $y = mx$ is the equation of a line through the origin.  If instead of $y$ and $x$ we use $dy$ and $dx$ as their names, then we're talking about the same straight line through the origin.  (Am I too tired or going crazy?)

Comment: We are not saying that $dy = f'(x) \ dx$ is the equation of a line. All it says is that a small change in $y$ is proportional to a small change in $x$.

Comment: I'm not sure.  Look at [Figure 5](https://i.imgur.com/6jBKPv3.png).  Notice how the point $R$ falls exactly on the tangent line.  The point $P$ (after going from $x$ to $dx$) moves to $R$, right on the tangent line.  So it does seem that $dy = f'(x) dx$.  (I'm saying this so that you can spot where my trouble is, but I begin to see that I'm not making a lot of sense here. See if you see where my trouble is.  I feel I'm wrong somewhere..)

Comment: Thank you.  I see where my trouble is.  For a change from $x$ to $\Delta x$, the vertical change in the tangent line $L(x)$ must be $L(x + \Delta x) - L(x) = f'(a) \Delta x$.  That's a measure of the vertical *change* in the tangent line, not the vertical coordinate of a point that falls on the tangent.  You spotted it right.  Thank you so much.

Comment: For any general line $y = mx + c$, $dy/dx = m$ which is just saying that $m$ is rise over run.